# update field in database with combobox item

Tags: c#, winforms, windowsformshost

i have data base and repository class plus interface like that\now i wana use some combobox with static items liek 100 200 300.. and whene i choose one of those item and prees the button i created before database update charge field(the field name in database)
my connection is ok i dont know how code the button

```
class apartment : Interfaceapartment
{
    private string Connection = "Data Source=.;initial catalog=apartment;integrated security=true";

    public bool update(int personID, int charge)
    {
        SqlConnection Conecting = new SqlConnection(Connection);
        try
        {
            string query = "Update myapartment Set charge=@charge Where personID=@ID";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, Conecting);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", personID);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("charge", charge);
            Conecting.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            Conecting.Close();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get the selected Value of ComboBox and pass it your update() function.

```
ChangedValue= combobox.SelectedValue.ToString();
```